# É possivel não permitir duplicidade em combinação de 2 colunas ou mais?

Tags: sql-server, chave-primária, restrição-único

Eu sei que o SQL Server possui as *primary Keys* e *iniques* para não permitir duplicidade de registros, mas é possível fazer isso através de 2 colunas ou mais?

Como exemplo, tenho uma tabela com coluna, casa e cachorro, onde os registros podem repetir as casas e também os cachorros, mas não pode repetir a mesma casa com o mesmo cachorro.

```
INSERT INTO table VALUES ('Laranja', 'Rex') << OK
INSERT INTO table VALUES ('Azul', 'Rex') << OK
INSERT INTO table VALUES ('Laranja', 'Tob') << OK
INSERT INTO table VALUES ('Azul', 'Tob') << OK
INSERT INTO table VALUES ('Laranja', 'Rex') << ERRO - DUPLICIDADE
```

É possível realizar isso apenas por criação de tabela?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sim, é possível, a forma mais simples seria assim:

```
CONSTRAINT nome_da_chave UNIQUE (coluna1, coluna2)
```

Se vai alterar uma tabela existente tem que fazer:

```
ALTER TABLE tabela ADD
```

antes disto.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Create/UniqueCompound.sql).

Isto está criando um índice com essas duas colunas como chave.

Se for uma chave primária então é só determinar que ambas fazem parte da primariedade já que toda primária é única.